# InAppBrowser.open opens in browser instead of the WebView

Tags: cordova, phonegap, inappbrowser, cordova-ios

The goal is to open a foreign url within the webview when the app starts.

I create fresh Cordova project:

```
cordova create test
cd test
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

I inline this script in `www/index.html`:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
    cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_self');
  }
</script>
```

I test the app with `cordova run ios`, app starts, and I get this:

> Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' appears in neither the script-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

So I add `'unsafe-inline'` to the Content Security Policy tag and it becomes this:

```
  <meta 
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="
      default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; 
      style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
      media-src *; 
      img-src 'self' data: content:;">
```

I test the app with `cordova run ios`, app starts, but it opens `https://google.com` in Safari:

[image]

How the hell do I open the url in the Cordova webview itself?

---

I also tried with `window.location="https://google.com"`, same behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was missing this in the `config.xml`:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

I somehow missed it from [the docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/).

> By default, navigations only to file:// URLs, are allowed. To allow others URLs, you must add  tags to your config.xml:

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#cordovainappbrowseropen) it looks like you need to set `target` to `_blank` to open in the `InAppBrowser`:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com', '_blank');
```

> **_self**: Opens in the **Cordova WebView** if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the **InAppBrowser**.
>
> **_blank**: Opens in the **InAppBrowser**.
>
> **_system**: Opens in the system's web browser.

Comment: Naah, that just opens [the inapp browser](https://imgur.com/a/cMiQT), instead, I want that URL to open in the Cordova's webview itself.